# Facebook chat hides Flash apps when open

Tags: facebook, flash, chat

While running a Flash app, if I open a new or existing Facebook chat window, my Flash content disappears. I can continue to hear music playing from the app and when I close/minimize the Facebook chat window, my Flash content reappears. Is this a known issue?

This is happening in Google Chrome 15 and Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 with Flash Player 11.

I checked this on my own Flash app as well as on another Flash app made by someone else and the same behaviour is occurring. It does not however hide non-Flash content.

It seems to be a bug with Facebook chat and Flash content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/:

If you are hosting an Adobe Flash application within Canvas, it is recommended that you set the wmode of the Flash object to "opaque":

...

Other modes (including the default mode, wmode="window", wmode="direct", and wmode="gpu") require us to hide your flash object when dialogs, popups, chat tabs, and ticker flyouts occur. This can be unpleasant or confusing for users.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#hide_flash_callback):

If you must use `wmode` values of `window` or `direct`, Canvas will automatically hide and display the Flash object when Dialogs, Ticket flyouts, Chat Tabs and Notifications display.

Developers who wish to provide a custom hide and display experience may pass a JavaScript function in the `hideFlashCallback` option for `FB.init`. This function will be executed whenever the Flash object is hidden or displayed due to user behavior (clicking on a Notification, etc.) and can be used by a developer to take the appropriate actions: hiding or displaying their Flash object.

```
FB.init({
    ...,
    hideFlashCallback: function(params) {
      if (params.state == 'opened') {
        $('#some-image').show();
        FB.Canvas.hideFlashElement(params.elem);                          
      } else {
        $('#some-image').hide();
        FB.Canvas.showFlashElement(params.elem);
    }
});
```