# Facebook Silverlight Canvas Hides Chat

Tags: c#, facebook, silverlight-5.0, facebook-canvas

Simply, **How** to send Silverlight hosted in Facebook Canvas to Back in order to avoid covering Chat Windows ?

I reviewed this related [Flash Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202256/facebook-chat-hides-flash-apps-when-open), but can't find the corresponding options in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the answer just after posting the question,

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"

        <param name="background" value="transparent" />    <---
        <param name="windowless" value="true" />           <---
```